# Information regarding SQL queries, stored with php

Tags: php, mysql, variables

So let me explain my problem, lets assume that I run query like so:

```
$myquery = sql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='example' LIMIT 0,1");
```

Now.. I want to store the retrieved name into a variable so I would do something like this:

```
    while ($myrow = sql_fetch_assoc($myquery)) {

            transfer_row($myrow);
                print"Name: $row_name";
    }
  $stored_name = $row_name;
```

**NOTE: transfer_row() is just a function I wrote that takes $myrow['name'] and stores it in $row_name, for easier reference**

Now, all is fine at this stage, here is where it gets interesting. Note that at this stage I still have a name assigned to $row_name. Further down the page I run another query to retrieve some other information from the table, and one of the things I need to retrieve is a list of names again, so I would simply run this query:

```
$myquery = sql_query("SELECT name, year FROM table WHERE DESC LIMIT 0,10");

    while ($myrow = sql_fetch_assoc($myquery)) {

        transfer_row($myrow);

    $year = $row_year;

        $link = "/$year";

        print "<li style=\"margin-bottom: 6px;\"><a href=\"$link\">$row_name</a>\n";

    }
```

Now, I want to write an if statement that executes something **if the $row_name from this query matches the $row_name from the old query**, this is why we stored the first $row_name inside the variable.

```
if ($row_name == $stored_name){
   // execute code
}
```

However as most of you know, this WONT work, the reason is, it simply takes $stored_name again and puts the new $row_name into $stored_name, so therefore the value of the first $row_name is lost, now it is crucial for my application that I access the first $row_name and compare it AFTER the second query has been run, what can I do here people? if nothing can be done what is an alternative to achieving something like this.

Thanks.

**EDIT, MY transfer_row() function:**

```
function transfer_row($myrow) {

    global $GLOBALS;

    if(is_array($myrow)) {
        foreach ($myrow as $key=>$value) {

            $key=str_replace(":","",$key);
            $GLOBALS["row_$key"] = $value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you put this if-statement? Inside the while-loop? Why can't you just compare without using "transfer_row"?

Comment: Your question is irrelevant, it makes no difference if I compare without transfer row.

Comment: Excuse me? It's absolutely relevant. If we don't know in which context this comparison will occur, we will assume it's inside the while-loop. In that case, David's answer is proper. Do that comparison before you execute the `transfer_row` call.

Comment: Okay, i will update my post

Comment: You stated that `it simply takes $stored_name again and puts the new $row_name into $stored_name` but that does not happen on the second code you have provided, so either we don't have all the code or you are wrong. Where is `$stored_name` altered in the second code?!

Comment: @Colandus No i was referring to what it does in the background, not what my code does. Basically, it shouldnt be doing that, because then we wouldnt have a problem

Comment: Obviously, the rudeness that I just deleted is not appropriate. I hope it stops here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query you are selecting the `name` field `WHERE name='example'` , Why are you quering then? You already have what you want.

Your are querying like:

`Hey? roll no 21 what is your roll no?`

So perform the second query only and use the if condition as :

```
if ($row_name == 'example'){
   // execute code
}
```

Does it make sense?

**Update**

```
//How about using prefix while storing the values in `$GLOBAL` ??

transfer_row($myrow, 'old_'); //for the first query
transfer_row($myrow, 'new_'); //for the second query

function transfer_row($myrow, $prefix) {

    global $GLOBALS;

    if(is_array($myrow)) {
        foreach ($myrow as $key=>$value) {

            $key=str_replace(":","",$key);
            $GLOBALS["$prefix"."row_$key"] = $value;
        }
    }

}

//Now compare as

if ($new_row_name == $old_row_name){
   // execute code
}

//You'll not need `$stored_name = $row_name;` any more
```

Comment: You are getting too focused on what the query is and what im using it for, if it wasnt obvious enough (its pretty obvious) the query and example I am using are just placeholders, in my  real application there is a need to do what I am doing and will not be possible with your "answer".

Comment: @user3332590 `the reason is, it simply takes $stored_name again and puts the new $row_name into $stored_name, so therefore the value of the first $row_name is lost` you know the problem make solution from there, see my update for some clue.

Answer (score 1):

Without you posting the code for the function transfer_row, we won't be able to give you an answer that exactly matches what you request, but I can give you an answer that will solve the problem at hand.

When matching to check if the names are the same, you can modify the if statement to the following.

```
if ($row_name == $myrow['name']){
   // execute code
}
```

What I suggest you do though, but since I don't have the code to the transfer_row function, is to pass a second variable to that function. The second variable will be a prefix for the variable name, so you can have unique values stored and saved.

Comment: Why wont you be able to help, i have clearly put, in bold writing what transfer_row() does. Your answer is un-accurate, if you read my post you would see that $row_name is the same as $myrow['name]

Comment: But we need the code to the function to modify it to allow for a prefix to be used instead of `row_` so you don't run into issues like this again. Or you could just use the associative array.

Comment: Then explain to me why this is, i have told you what it does.

Comment: here is my code function:                                                  function transfer_row($myrow) {

 global $GLOBALS;

 if(is_array($myrow)) {
  foreach ($myrow as $key=>$value) {

   $key=str_replace(":","",$key);
   $GLOBALS["row_$key"] = $value;
  }
 }

}

Answer (score 1):

Refrain from using the `transfor_row` function in the second call so your comparison becomes:
`if ($myrow['name'] == $row_name)`

If you need to use this function, you could do an assignment before the second database call:

```
$stored_name = $row_name;
...
transfer_row($myrow);
```

Comment: Please read ALL my post, your second option wont work as i have already done this.

Comment: You need to do `$stored_name = $row_name;` **before** the second call to transfer_row. There is no reason this wouldn't work.

Comment: I dont know what else to say to say to you, you can clearly see in my code that i have done this. everything you see in my post is posted in the same order as it is in my code.

Comment: I think the problem is that we don't really understand what you want to achieve. You pasted 3 code snippets. The exact location of the assignment and the if statement is what matters here.

Comment: `If you need to use this function, you could do an **assignment before the second database call**:`. This means: Do the assignment before your second database call. You cannot 'save' a variable by copying it to another variable when it has already been overwritten.